# Подключение внешних файлов

Tags: javascript

почему выдает ошибку `make is not defined`? есть 2 файла. index.php - главный файл, func.js - внешний/подключаемый:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Этот текст не должен стираться при выполнении функции make();</h1>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ns = document.createElement('script');
    ns.type = "text/javascript";
    ns.src = "func.js";
    document.head.appendChild(ns);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     make(); //make is not defined
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

func.js

```
function make(){
   document.write("SUCCESS");
}
```

P.S. да, нужно подключать файл именно таким образом.

P.S.S. понятно, что можно обернуть вызов .onload'ом, но тогда исчезнет весь контент

Comment: В тот момент, когда вы вызываете функцию make(), файл func.js еще не выполнен

Comment: а как исправить?

Comment: Дождаться загрузки func.js и только потом выполнять make(). P.S. Что в действительности-то надо сделать? А то может подход неправильный выбрали.

Answer (score 1):

Можете загрузить нужный скрипт аяксом,скажем, при нажатии кнопки или ещё какого-то события.
Пример тут http://www.coolwebmasters.com/codes-and-scripts/5197-dinamicheskaya-podgruzka-skriptov-pri-pomoschi-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не...

```
<script>
    var ns = document.createElement('script');
    ns.type = "text/javascript";
    // выполняем функцию ПОСЛЕ загрузки скрипта
    ns.onload = function () { 
        make();
    };
    ns.src = "func.js";
    document.head.appendChild(ns);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать через setTimeout() и установить через сколько секунд вызывать функцию

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>функции make()</title>
        <script src='js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js' ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Этот текст не должен стираться при выполнении функции make();</h1>  



<script>
    var ns = document.createElement('script');
    ns.type = "text/javascript";
    ns.src = "func.js";
    document.head.appendChild(ns);
</script>

<script>
     make(); //make is not defined
     setTimeout(make, 2000); // можно сделать через таймаут 
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

если не помогло поищите в гугле: **динамическая загрузка js**